# YouTube Data API v3, Web Application, 403 usageLimits accessNotConfigured

Tags: youtube-api

I'm having trouble when trying to access the YouTube Data API v3. This is the json response I get whenever I send a valid request:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

Example of one of my valid requests:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&q=funny&key=*my_valid_api_browser_key*
```

Here is a screenshot of my services setting in the Google APIs Console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMesW.jpg

In addition, I have registered the application and it has a Project ID and Client ID. I have also tried swapping the api_key parameter in the example above, one of my valid request URLs, with a valid api *server* key (and I believe this will only work if the request comes from the IP address associated with the key, which I can do because I can make the API request from the correct server); however, I still get the exact same result.

Is the YouTube Data API v3 public yet? It appears that it was released publicly on December 12, 2012 when this video for the YouTube Data API v3 was released: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlcWiP7OLFI. I guess I could be wrong though.

Any other ideas on why I could be getting this particular response instead of a response that has the expected list of videos matching my query?

Comment: That should work. Could you email me your API Key so that I could take a closer look as to what's going on? jeffy at google dot com

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Just shot you an email with the browser API key.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like there's something odd going on, and I'll follow up with some folks internally to figure out what it is, then report back on this thread if it's of general interest.

Comment: Yes, I'd be interested in a report back on the Referer field whitelist for the API Browser key because it's supposed to act as added security. Maybe I was trying to use it incorrectly (I had \*.mydomainname.com/\* listed as a referer, just as the example below the textarea displayed when I was creating a new browser key).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jeff, your email recommendation resolved my issue. I removed all lines from the Referers field. Now, in my Google API console, on the API Access screen for this project, under the section titled 'Key for browser apps (with referers)' has a 'Referers' field that reads --> Referers: Any referer allowed.

Now, I get an accurate JSON response from the API.

Comment: In that way all referers are allowed. I am struggling trying to set that field to `chrome-extension://myExtensionId` so that only requests from my Google Chrome extension are allowed (otherwise other people who know the key could use my quota). Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Sadly this hasn't worked for me. After removing all referers, I still get the same output from the latest php version (search.php):
A service error occurred: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&q=dogs&maxResults=25&key={my_api_key}: (403) Access Not Configured

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, removing all referers doesn't seems to solve the issue as I think YouTube API saves your IP and previously added referers and block it, I had to create another API key without any referers and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you using google api v3, this is simple way to solve that problem, you only need to enable `youtube api` via Google Console Dashboard. https://console.developers.google.com