# YouTube Data API v3, 403 usageLimits accessNotConfigured

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My application using youtube data API v3 for social login and signup. The last 8 months work fine but suddenly it occurs error like this.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project [PROJECT_ID] before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=[PROJECT_ID] then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=[PROJECT_ID]"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project [PROJECT_ID] before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=[PROJECT_ID] then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
 }
}
```

I've searched solve the error found [few answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163844/youtube-data-api-v3-web-application-403-usagelimits-accessnotconfigured) but most of them don't suggest collect answer and what is the real problem.

Answers say create new Project and make new clientID and OAuth. It's working but it requires new Signup for my application existing users.

And I tried to contact google API for Verification API but google send me

"Based on the type of request you’ve submitted you can skip the verification process if your app does not need to display an icon. If you decide to skip the verification process, it won’t impact the existing functionality of your app, as long as the scopes used by your project don’t change."

Comment: And I've tried remove all referrer and create new Oauth Client is not working. Always same error return.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me and after searching I couldn't find anything helpful.

I found this which is probably what is happening:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141187677

I guess YouTube disabled our API Projects but I didn't receive any notice or anything.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's still looking for a solution, I found one that worked for me. In my situation, the API had suddenly stopped working without notice or warning. The error message returned by the API (the same one cited above) was incorrect, as the API had been used successfully for years, was not disabled, and had not exceeded usage limits. I had tried creating a new API key for the project, but the result was the same.

**SOLUTION:** I created a new PROJECT first, then created a new API key for the new project. Apparently, the issue was at the project level for whatever reason, so this was all it took to resolve the problem. (This and placing the new API key in my code, of course!) **I hope this helps someone.** :)

Answer (score 0):

Same here! Youtube set my Quota to zero after the verification process without any notice. Now im looking for a way to contact them and understand what I have to change to enable it again.